# I'm interested in knowing more about transfer codes withdrawing bitcoin

Tags: trading, fraud, withdrawal

I purchased bitcoin via blockchain and transfer it to Cardonetradingoption.com via an individual I was corresponding with. I sent this person money three time because he advised me that I needed to do that to upgrade. I started with $800 then he said to upgrade and surpass $5k I have to send in more so I transfer another $1250. Later he wanted more so that I could upgrade pass 10k. He wanted $2400  but I was only able to send him $800.
This was where everything became fishy. I wanted to withdraw and is unable to do so for the past month. The balance only rose to just under 10K because he insisted that I should send the difference, which I didn't have.
I can see the account I open with cardone trading and I can see my balance but I cannot withdraw and when I tried it's asking for a transfer code, which I know nothing about. This individual is refusing to help me to withdraw.
CAN YOU HELP ME SORT THIS OUT. WAS THIS A SCAM WHICH I AM SUSPECTING THAT IT IS.

Comment: Yes, this most definitely sounds like a scam.

Comment: You got scammed. Your money is gone. Lol. How do people keep falling for these?